# DocumentDB listchangestreams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

Following the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html) we are trying to list all change streams using the command

```
cursor = new DBCommandCursor(db,
    db.runCommand(
        {aggregate: 1,
            pipeline: [{$listChangeStreams: 1}], cursor:{}}));
```

We are running this in the MongoSH provided in the MongoDB Compass application. But we are getting an error that says: "ReferenceError: DBCommandCursor is not defined". I am completely lost on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the command without wrapping it in a `DBCommandCursor`:

```
db.runCommand(
    {aggregate: 1,
        pipeline: [{$listChangeStreams: 1}], cursor:{}});
```

Your change streams will be listed in the `cursor.firstBatch` array of the results.

If you need to see more results (i.e., if the default batch size is too small), you can use the `batchSize` parameter:

```
db.runCommand(
    {aggregate: 1,
        pipeline: [{$listChangeStreams: 1}], cursor:{"batchSize": 1000}});
```

Be sure to connect to the [cluster endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/endpoints.html) (or directly to the primary instance endpoint), otherwise you will get this error:

```
MongoServerError: Aggregation stage not supported: '$listChangeStreams'
```

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I didn't try that.